# How to change the colors of Section and sub section heading without affecting the color on minitoc?

Tags: pdftex

[image]I have set the color of the minitoc as blue and I want to keep it that way. However, when I am changing the section or subsection heading color, that color is appearing on the particular heading in the minitoc. How to disable that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a small but compilable example document with your question that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! I have added an image of the case.

Comment: like @siracusa wrote: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. From the image it is impossible to reproduce the problem / help you (I think you need to add, stripped down versions of, `main.tex` and `prac.tex`